# $http.get com Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, http

buscando dados de uma api através do $http.get, porém encontro um erro.

Minha requisição dentro de um service:

```
app.service('pessoas',function($http){
     this.getHumanos = function(callback){
            $http.get('http://private-ff1c4-grupo.apiary-mock.com/pessoas').success(callback);
        };
});
```

e Aqui onde dentro do meu controller onde eu pego os dados:

```
app.controller('servico',function($scope, pessoas){
    pessoas.getHumanos(function(data){      
            $scope.pessoas = data;
    });
});
```

Erro mostrado no console:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token i
    at Object.parse (native)
    at pc (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:14:208)
    at Zb (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:76:379)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:77:237
    at s (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:7:302)
    at Zc (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:77:219)
    at c (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:78:349)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:112:20
    at l.$eval (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:125:305)
    at l.$digest (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:122:398)
```

Comment: Tente colocar o `error` chamando tambem o callback. _Observação_: essas funções `success` e `error` está depreciado, manipule com **promise**.

Comment: Olá, eu coloquei o error também, não entendi a parte do promise, mas bem, continuo obtendo o mesmo erro.

Comment: Cara isso não é erro de sintaxe? O que é esse `i`? Não tem um `i` perdido no codigo?

Comment: Não tem nenhum i no código já revisei várias vezes haha, Olha aqui: https://github.com/HenriRique/angularHttp

Comment: Na resposta da url `http://private-ff1c4-grupo.apiary-mock.com/pessoas` a chave **idade** não está entre aspas. Tente deixa-lo entre aspas.

Comment: Funcionou Amigo, só mais uma pequena dúvida ele está me retornando array, como eu faço para fazer o loop no ng-repeat? pq a lista está aparecendo vazia

Comment: `ng-repeat="item in pessoas"` o nome `item` pode ser qualquer um que você deseja e `pessoas` é o nome do `$scope` que contém os dados. Se você está utilizando um `<ul>` o ng-repeat deve ser colocado no `<li>`, ou seja, sempre no elemento que você deseja repetir. `<li ng-repeat="item in pessoas"> {{item.nome}} </li>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu executei o seu código sem nenhum problema. Talvez o erro esteja sendo causado por algum elemento não mencionado no código postado.

Segue o exemplo funcional - clique em <kbd>> Executar Trecho de Código</kbd>.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.service('pessoas',function($http){
     this.getHumanos = function(callback){
            $http.get('http://private-ff1c4-grupo.apiary-mock.com/pessoas').success(callback);
        };
});

app.controller('servico',function($scope, pessoas){
    pessoas.getHumanos(function(data){      
            $scope.pessoas = data;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="servico">
  <p ng-repeat="x in pessoas">
    {{x.idade}} {{x.nome}}
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT 1**

O seu erro está no callback. Altere para:

```
app.service('pessoas',function($http){
     this.getHumanos = function(callback){
        $http.get('http://private-ff1c4-grupo.apiary-mock.com/pessoas').then(function successCallback(response) {
            callback(response);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.error('Error: ' + response);
        });
    };
});
```

**EDIT 2**

O motivo da alteração.

**Primeiro:** Sempre que trabalhar com chamadas ajax no angular tenha dois métodos. Um de sucesso. E outro que muitos não usam e é importante o método de fracasso ou de erro. Assim caso algum problema ocorra é mais fácil rastrea-lo, além do que fica melhor para o usuário final.

**Segundo:**

O método que sempre uso indicando o *sucess* é o *then* e não o *sucess* propriamente dito. Logo acredito que isso possa estar gerando o problema reportado devido a chamada ou passaem de parametros para o cal;back incorreto.

Ainda acrescento um artigo interessante.

[Quando usar service e factory no angular](http://blog.concretesolutions.com.br/2015/03/angularjs-quando-usar-service-e-factory/)

Comment: Você tem como explicar o motivo de ter que fazer essa alteração? Sua resposta pode estar correta, mas está vaga.

Comment: Eu fiz essa modificação mas não entendi a parte do return ali em baixo. Só que ai ele fica falando que minha função getHumanos não é definida quando eu chamo ela.

Comment: No service deve ser usado o `this` e não o `return`. Utilize dessa maneira: `this.getHumanos = function(callback){ ... }`

Comment: @jbueno feito! Inclui a explicação

Comment: @oOAkiraOo vlw pelo toque já corrigi